# Integer solutions to potential parabola $y^{2} = 16 + 12x$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Through a series of maneuvers in an attempt to find a solution to a math problem, I have this.

$$y^{2} = 16 + 12x$$

I identify this as a potential parabola. I need a find a way to get all integer solutions $(x,y)$ to said parabola.

I have attempted to graph it and look for ideas but return blank.

Answer (score 1):

So you want integers $y$ such that $y^2 \equiv 16 \equiv 4 \mod 12$.  So $y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ (which is true if and only if $y$ is even) and $y^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ (which is true whenever $y$ is not divisible by $3$).  Thus $y$ can be any integer that is divisible by $2$ but not by $3$, and $x = (y^2-16)/12$.

Answer (score 0):

- HINT

$$y^2=16+12x$$

$$(2m)^2=16+12x ,~ y=2m$$

$$m^2=4+3x$$

$$x=\frac{m^2-4}{3}, x≥-1$$

Then check:

$$m:=3k-1 \\ m:=3k-2$$